I used the laso tool to cut some geometry and i have too many vertices that do nothing, is there any way to remove em quickly and automaticaly?
Often times i struggle with poor geometry and have subdivided parts where theres no faces. I'm curious of a way to select and loose or isolated vertex like the one in the image and dissolving them ty!


In Edit Mode select all, hit X and choose Limited Dissolve. Then in the tool options at the bottom left adjust the threshold angle to make sure you do not lose edges with low angles.

Go to Edit mode, select one of the unwanted vertices, go to menu > Select > Similar > Amount of connecting edges (shortcut Shift G), check and deselect unwanted behaviours(maybe at angles), then press X > Dissolve vertices.

